# how to extract features/metrics from the dependency graph within Frama-C

Tags: c, metrics, frama-c

I am a PG student and doing my research on code clone detection. For this purpose I made program dependency graphs of C code using a tool named [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com). Now I have to extract features/metrics from these program dependency graphs for further processing. Can Frama-C extract metrics from program dependency graph? If not, is there any other tool that can?

```
void sumProd1A(int n) {
    double sum = 0.0; //C1
    double prod = 1.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        prod = prod * i;
        foo2(sum, prod);
    }
}
void main()
{
    printf("\nsumProd1A_Cordy: %lf ");
    sumProd1A(4);
}
```

This is the actual code, which converts into this program dependency graph

```
[pdg] ====== PDG GRAPH COMPUTED ======
[pdg] PDG for foo2
 {n38}: InCtrl
 {n39}: VarDecl : x_0
   <-[a--]- 40
 {n40}: In1
   <-[a--]- 39
   <-[--d]- 43
 {n41}: VarDecl : x_1
   <-[a--]- 42
 {n42}: In2
   <-[a--]- 41
   <-[--d]- 43
 {n43}: OutRet
[pdg] PDG for printf
 {n44}: InCtrl
 {n45}: VarDecl : x_0
   <-[a--]- 46
 {n46}: In1
   <-[a--]- 45
 {n47}: OutRet
 {n48}: In("\nsumProd1A_Cordy: %lf "[bits 0 to 183])
   <-[--d]- 47
[pdg] PDG for sumProd1A
 {n49}: InCtrl
   <-[-c-]- 55
   <-[-c-]- 56
   <-[-c-]- 57
   <-[-c-]- 58
   <-[-c-]- 59
   <-[-c-]- 60
   <-[-c-]- 61
   <-[-c-]- 62
   <-[-c-]- 63
   <-[-c-]- 64
   <-[-c-]- 65
   <-[-c-]- 66
   <-[-c-]- 67
   <-[-c-]- 68
 {n50}: VarDecl : n
   <-[a--]- 51
   <-[--d]- 59
 {n51}: In1
   <-[a--]- 50
   <-[--d]- 59
 {n52}: VarDecl : sum
   <-[a--]- 55
   <-[a-d]- 61
   <-[--d]- 64
 {n53}: VarDecl : prod
   <-[a--]- 56
   <-[a-d]- 62
   <-[--d]- 65
 {n54}: VarDecl : i
   <-[a--]- 57
   <-[--d]- 59
   <-[--d]- 61
   <-[--d]- 62
   <-[a-d]- 66
 {n55}: double sum = 0.0;
   <-[--d]- 61
 {n56}: double prod = 1.0;
   <-[--d]- 62
 {n57}: i = 1;
   <-[--d]- 59
   <-[--d]- 61
   <-[--d]- 62
   <-[--d]- 66
 {n58}: while(1)
   <-[-c-]- 58
   <-[-c-]- 59
   <-[-c-]- 60
   <-[-c-]- 61
   <-[-c-]- 62
   <-[-c-]- 63
   <-[-c-]- 64
   <-[-c-]- 65
   <-[-c-]- 66
   <-[-c-]- 67
 {n59}: i <= n
   <-[-c-]- 58
   <-[-c-]- 59
   <-[-c-]- 60
   <-[-c-]- 61
   <-[-c-]- 62
   <-[-c-]- 63
   <-[-c-]- 64
   <-[-c-]- 65
   <-[-c-]- 66
   <-[-c-]- 67
 {n60}: block
   <-[-c-]- 61
   <-[-c-]- 62
   <-[-c-]- 63
   <-[-c-]- 64
   <-[-c-]- 65
 {n61}: sum += (double)i;
   <-[--d]- 61
   <-[--d]- 64
 {n62}: prod *= (double)i;
   <-[--d]- 62
   <-[--d]- 65
 {n63}: Call35-InCtrl : foo2(sum,prod);
   <-[-c-]- 64
   <-[-c-]- 65
 {n64}: Call35-In1 : foo2(sum,prod);
 {n65}: Call35-In2 : foo2(sum,prod);
 {n66}: i ++;
   <-[--d]- 59
   <-[--d]- 61
   <-[--d]- 62
   <-[--d]- 66
 {n67}: break;
   <-[-c-]- 58
   <-[-c-]- 59
   <-[-c-]- 60
   <-[-c-]- 61
   <-[-c-]- 62
   <-[-c-]- 63
   <-[-c-]- 64
   <-[-c-]- 65
   <-[-c-]- 66
   <-[-c-]- 67
 {n68}: return;
[pdg] PDG for main
 {n69}: InCtrl
   <-[-c-]- 70
   <-[-c-]- 71
   <-[-c-]- 72
   <-[-c-]- 73
   <-[-c-]- 74
 {n70}: Call39-InCtrl : printf("\nsumProd1A_Cordy: %lf ");
   <-[-c-]- 71
 {n71}: Call39-In1 : printf("\nsumProd1A_Cordy: %lf ");
 {n72}: Call40-InCtrl : sumProd1A(4);
   <-[-c-]- 73
 {n73}: Call40-In1 : sumProd1A(4);
 {n74}: return;
```

This is the program dependency graph from which I have to extract features.

The metrics I want to extract are:

> number of assignments that come after Declarations,
>
> Declarations coming after Control (e.g. i < count,for, while, if, switch etc.)
>
> numbers of times nested iterations occur
>
> numbers of times nested selections occur etc.